# Tag synonym request: [display-resolution] -> [resolution]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[screen-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) and [monitor-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/monitor-resolution) are already synonyms of [resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution). [display-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/display-resolution) should be too.

Comment: @Braiam curious: despite the general popularity of that question, why didn't it happen? (Also, I'm asking for the other way around - I see no problem in taking `resolution` to be the resolution of some medium.)

Comment: The main tag should be unambigous. You see people creating display-resolution because *that's what it's actually called*. And it wasn't applied because there's no one to be operative around here. There are a bunch of merge, burnination and unsynonymization that despite of being consensuated they are never applied (some predates more than a year without being acted upon).

Comment: Who cares what it's actually called? Policykit is actually called Polkit, yet the tag is Policykit because that's what Ubuntu calls it.

Comment: "Polkit (formerly **PolicyKit**)" it was PolicyKit, that Ubuntu hasn't applied that is irrelevant. If you want you can ask for the tag to be renamed too.

Comment: @Braiam I chose to get `polkit` synonymized and asked Seth to do so. Yet the fact is there are over 1200 questions tagged `resolution`, including 7 renames from screen-/monitor-r, and 74 tagged display-r. Things might "actually" be called foo, but people prefer bar.

Comment: I agree with Muru (VTKO). It' better to have the system adhere to the humans then to try to educate the humans how to use the system... (That's like trying to herd cats...)

Comment: I agree with @Braiam here, display-resolution should be the master. After all, we aren't talking about video resolution. Or photo resolution. Or webcam resolution. We're talking about display resolution.

Comment: @Seth either way, as long as we only have one tag. So, can you do r -> display-r then?